# Calling CFC's on another folder level

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I have a page that I use cfc's on. Like this:

```
<cfset cfcDashboard = new dashboard()>
<cfset grab_image = cfcdashboard.getPicture()>
```

How do I call the cfc's if they are inside of a folder? As of right now they only work if they are on the same level or inside the same folder? How do you call a cfc that is on a different level?

Or am I not understanding the purpose of the cfc?

Comment: Hard to say.   What do you consider to be the purpose of a cfc?

Comment: i consider the cfc something to store all my functions that i can use any where in the app but have to figure out someway of calling it from different levels of the app. People have provided me many examples that I appreciate tremendously but for some reason I am unable to get them to work.. only way i found to make it work is adding the same cfc in all those folders... but this definitely does not seem the proper way :/

Comment: Option 3 from Tomalak's answer is the best way to achieve that.  It's what we do, for the most part.  The only time we do otherwise is when we are creating remote functions to use with ajax.  It could be a function of our own meagre talents, but the only way to get that to work is to have the cfc in the same directory as the page attempting to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `new` keyword is syntactic sugar for this call:

```html
<cfset cfcDashboard = createObject("component", "Dashboard")>
```

The rules how ColdFusion resolves CFC names are [in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e17.html).

> If you use a `cfinvoke` or `cfobject` tag, or the `CreateObject`
>   function, to access the CFC from a CFML page, ColdFusion searches
>   directories in the following order:
>
> 1. Local directory of the calling CFML page
> 2. Web root
> 3. Directories specified on the Custom Tag Paths page of ColdFusion Administrator

You can use dot notation that corresponds to any of the defined search paths.

```html
<cfset myDashboard = createObject("component", "my.custom.Dashboard")>
<cfset myDashboard = new my.custom.Dashboard()>
```

Will find (where `.` means the current template directory and `/` means the web root):

- `./my/custom/Dashboard.cfc`
- `/my/custom/Dashboard.cfc`
- `any/custom/tag/path/my/custom/Dashboard.cfc`

Going "up" is not possible.

Comment: hmmm so you cant go up a level? so if your profile page is inside profiles folder but the cfc is on the index.cfm level it will not find it?

Comment: can i give you the example I am trying to get to work I cant figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: i have a dashboard.cfm inside the dashboard folder I am trying to just get up to the main area the next level where dashboard.cfc is

Comment: `<cfset cfcDashboard = createObject("component", "Dashboard")>
<cfset grab_image = cfcdashboard.getPicture()>`

Comment: You should never have to go up. Have you tried using an absolute component name (i.e. one that starts at the web root)?

Comment: my example works on the main root but does not if i stick it inside of a folder

Comment: Just answer my question, please.

Comment: im sorry i dont know what u mean

Comment: put the function name there?

Comment: all my cfc is this my component doesnt have a name

Comment: `<cfcomponent>

<!--- Get users picture --->
<cffunction name="getPicture" access="public" returntype="query">
 <cfset var grab_image = ''>
   <cfquery name="grab_image">
       SELECT *
       FROM dbo.Users
       WHERE employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#session.employee_number#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
     </cfquery>
   <cfreturn grab_image>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>`

Comment: **Have you tried using an absolute component name (i.e. one that starts at the web root)?** ...seriously. Instead of spamming the comments, please try to read and understand the answer, read and understand the docs that I helpfully link to. Please, stop spamming the comments, this is abusive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100063/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 0):

Granted there is no way to go "UP" but there is a way you can start at the top level of your website.

Place this line in your root Application.cfc file

```
<cfset this.directory = getDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() ) />
<cfset this.mappings['/app'] = this.directory />
```

Then when you type your cfinvoke line type it like this

Of course, you want to replace [name of subfolder] with the folder your component is located and [name of component] when the name of your component. Everything else is the normal cfinvoke syntax.

So in a roundabout way, there is a way to start "up" from a sub-folder.